# Session-based authentication security

Tags: security, https

As far as I know, after the **authentication** phase, when the user has sent his username and password to the server, using basic authentication over or without https, the server send a sessionId to the client, and after that client use this **sessionId** for each subsequent request.

- My question here is, how can a **sessionId** can be secured for each request so that it can not be hijacked by a hacker ? because the sessionId is sent as cookie (form the server after the submission of the username and password) and can be easily (**as far as I know if I'm right**) eavesdropped.
- My second question is about grasping the difference between token-based authentication and sessionId-base authentication. I read many explanation of the difference between them but I have some trouble to understand that.

best ragards.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

> is sent as cookie and can be easily eavesdropped.

Not if it was sent via HTTPS (you have added this as a tag). Which is rather the point of HTTPS.

There are other attacks which can compromise a web session but that's a different and longer discussion.

> My second question

Should have been posted as a separate question.

A session id is specifically bound to the session and can therefore reference state information beyond that required for authentication (e.g. your shopping basket) while token authentication exclusively deals with authentication.

Comment: Good explanation but, if we are using HTTP protocol normally there will be security threats and the the sessionId can be hijacked isn't ? as for the difference between token-base and session-based authentication it is very clear now and it seems that's what exactly I need to know because this is the major difference between them, so thanks for that. Could you reply my first question please ?

Comment: 1) You tagged your question with HTTPS, not HTTP, Yes, over HTTP its realtively simple to gain control over the session by eavesdropping in the absence of other security measures 2) Session can be hijacked over SSL but not by eavesdropping alone

Comment: In case of https with with cookie disabled the sessionId will be passed in the URL rewriting will be used and in this case the sessionId will be visible even  when using https. What do you think about that ?

Comment: You're extending the scope of this question. If you are using an HTTP session management system which has an option of using something other than cookies than for communicating the session id, then other attack surfaces may be exposed. But, no in the scenario you describe the session id will not be exposed to a third party.

Comment: I'm wondering about how to secure the sessionId even if we're using https in case when cookie is disabled, and that's not out of the scope of this question Sir.

Answer (score 1):

You can set the **httpOnly** flag to assure that the cookie cannot be read from javascript.

The secure flag can assure that the cookie can only be transported over an **SSL/TLS** based connection.